# How to convert some files from dos format to unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dos2unix

I know how to change file format from dos to unix by use `dos2unix`, but how can I change ALL the files will under a directory tree. Can `dos2unix` change files recursively?

for example, I have some files like following:

```
TOPDIR
|
+-----dir1
|      |
|      +---file1,file2, file3
|
+-----dir2
       |
       +---file4,file5
```

How can I change them in one time, or use some shell scripts?

Comment: You should start to play around with unix commands. There is no other way to learn how to use the power they offer. You have to try yourself and explore and conquer that environment step by step. Do it, it is worth it.

Comment: Regarding that, it's always helpful to read the manpage or `$CMD --help`, since some programs (e.g. `grep`) have a recursive flag `-R` that does this for you. Also if the count of files is not too high (i.e. in the order of a few hundred) you can use the extended glob capabilities of shells like `zsh` to do `dos2unix **/*`.

Comment: @filmor, I only can use `bsh` on my server, and seems `dos2unix` has no `-R` option

Answer (score 7, accepted):

better to do `find /path -type -f -exec dos2unix '{}' \;`

Comment: +1. I copy-paste from my example with *.c pattern, but for all files -type f is better. :-)

Comment: @Andrey Dmitriev, what is the different between: `find /path -type -f -exec dos2unix '{}' \;` and `find /path -type f -exec dos2unix {} +`

Comment: The plus syntax spawns fewer jobs; with the semicolon it's one new process for every file.

Comment: on debian (wheezy) i get `find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter` so i had to use `find /path/ -type f -exec dos2unix '{}' \;`

Answer (score 1):

`find /path -name '*' -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;`

Comment: Why did you add `-name '*'`?

Comment: In case you need to apply `dos2unix` to some files only, makes the example more easy to understand, imo (e.g. you can write `-name '*.c'`)

Comment: ...Maybe the thinking behind this answer is that `-name '*'` would exclude dot files (`.*`)? Well, in any case, it doesn't (it used to in some cases, but now it doesn't -- so don't assume it does). For example, `.foo`  files or files in `.git` directories would be processed. Those files would have to be excluded, e.g., `find path \( -name ".*" -prune \) -o \( -type f  -print \)`  (note: you couldn't start this with `find . (etc)` or else it would exclude everything)

Answer (score 0):

```
dos2unix -k `find . -type f`
find . -type f -exec dos2unix -k '{}' \;
find . -type f -print | xargs dos2unix -k
```

Any of above command can be used from TOPDIR